# Windbg lm: what does "deferred" mean?

Tags: .net, windbg, crash-dumps

I'm debugging a crash dump file for a .NET 2.0 assembly in WinDbg.

When I type "lm" into WinDbg, I get a long list of loaded modules like this:

```
723c0000 72950000 mscorwks   (deferred)  
.  
.
```

What does "deferred" mean here?
Do I need to worry about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It just means no symbols were loaded yet for this module. So don't worry about that.

---

See [lm (List Loaded Modules)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The symbol type immediately follows the module name. This column is not labeled. For more information about the various status values, see [Symbol Status Abbreviations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you have loaded symbols, the symbol file name follows this column.

and [Deferred Symbol Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/ff541840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> By default, symbol information is not actually loaded when the target modules are loaded. Instead, symbols are loaded by the debugger as they are needed. This is called deferred symbol loading or lazy symbol loading.

and [Symbol Status Abbreviations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Abbreviation:** deferred
>
> **Meaning:** The module has been loaded, but the debugger has not attempted to load the symbols. Symbols will be loaded when needed. See [Deferred Symbol Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: Type `ld *` to load all symbols and change "deferred" into "public pdb symbols" or "private pdb symbols".